# Appengine urlfetch issue (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use urlfetch to make a request to my application (the same application which is sending the request) however, it doesn't work.

My code is as follows;

```
uploadurl = 'http://myapp.appspot.com/posturl'

result = urlfetch.fetch(
             url=uploadurl,
             payload=data,
             method=urlfetch.POST,
             headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
```

There is no error at all when I call this, and everything seems to work correctly, however the request never arrives. For debugging purposes, I changed the uploadurl to a different application which I own and it worked fine. Any ideas why I can't send requests using urlfetch to the same application?

The full (real) url that I would call is made by

```
session = str(os.urandom(16).encode('hex'))
uploadurl = blobstore.create_upload_url('/process?session=' + session)
```

So I can't understand how that could be incorrect as the url is made for me.

Thanks.

Comment: did you try your real uploadurl with urllib to see if it's correct? and that your payload is actually made of valid form data? plus, urlfetch exhausts your quotas, bear that in mind

Comment: I tried it with urllib and it did exactly the same thing. I've looked at the realurl it is trying to POST to and it's perfect. Data wasn't valid formdata, it was actually an image, so I've changed it to "image/jpeg" rather than "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which made no difference at all.

Comment: logs in appengine? do you have some more relevant code you can post? also, add a deadline option to your fetch call (like `deadline=60`, since it's measured in seconds and 60 is the max allowed for your application) and see if it works (the default otherwise is 5 seconds)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you're verifying that the request "never arrives". The blobstore URLs are not handled by your application's actual code, but by the App Engine runtime itself, so if you're looking in the logs you won't see that request there.

Comment: I thought once the upload was complete, the other URL was requested "/process?session=' + session" in this case. Plus, I'm sending an image and it doesn't get saved into the blobstore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible, to prevent endless loop. From the urlfetch api documentation [page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/):

> To prevent an app from causing an endless recursion of requests, a
>   request handler is not allowed to fetch its own URL. It is still
>   possible to cause an endless recursion with other means, so exercise
>   caution if your app can be made to fetch requests for URLs supplied by
>   the user.